# How to get an errored message in Talend in order to send it by email?

Tags: sql, talend

Does anyone possible know how to get an errored message in Talend?

I have a `tMSSqlInput` ==> `tMSSqlOutput`. (see schema below).

If an error is thrown, I'd like to get it in mail body, and send it, instead of sendind a message by default.

I found something like :

- `globalMap.put("errorCode", input_row.message);`
- `"The message is: "+(String)globalMap.get("errorCode")`

But I dont know, where to place the first line. Obviously it would be somewhere inside the `tMSSqlOutput`. But where?

Thank y'all in advance.

[image: schema]

Comment: most talend components including tmysqloutput has Error Messages (after) which is available once the component has failed or succeeded. you can access the value in these variables post the component in next component say tMysqloutput --->(OnComponentOK)---->tJava ...in tJava you can see what was there in the tmysqloutput component by using below expression - System.out.println((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlOutput_1_ERROR_MESSAGE"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most talend components including tmysqloutput has Error Messages (after) which is available once the component has failed or succeeded. you can access the value in these variables post the component in next component say tMysqloutput --->(OnComponentOK)---->tJava ...in tJava you can see what was there in the tmysqloutput component by using below expression - System.out.println((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlOutput_1_ERROR_MESSAGE"));

You can store this error message in a global variable and then use this global variable in your tSendEmail component.
to assign a value to global variable you would use globalMap.out("variableName",value);
to fetch this value 
(String)globalMap.get("variableName")

Another way would be to add tLogCatcher in your application and enable Die on error option in your components. What will happen is that now when an exception is raised tLogCAtcher will catch the message and code and you can connect tLogCatcher to other components to fetch this error code and use it in next components like tSendEmail for sending email

Comment: it will print error only if there is an exception happening. can you put screenshot of your job. Also try with tlogcatcher also

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. Awesome. Brilliant. But now, in one job, I have many tables to Synchronize, but I do not want to create one tJava for each component. I prefer to use tLogCatcher. It detects in case of error. But how to get an error message,in one global variable? Merci

Comment: I did something like row1.message  =  to get an errored message. But I can't assign it into a global variable in tJava, doing `globalMap.put("errorCode", row1.message);` Dunno why it isn't working!!

Comment: try to use tJavaRow (which repeats for evey row) and in that you can concaenate all error messages. Better would be to write data from tlogcather into a tfileoutpudelimited and next read this file  and you have all options you need to transform the error messages as you want

Comment: It's not that clear, what you're talking about. I am very beginner in this )

Answer (score 1):

What we did was, join all the components to the tRowGenerator using the "OnComponentError" link. Now, in the tRowGenerator, you can create a column name like ErrorDesc and then in the Environment variables, use the ternary operator with the global variable to get the error message.

> (((String)globalMap.get("tRowGenerator_1_ERROR_MESSAGE"))!= null)? "Generate SP Inputs " + ((String)globalMap.get("tRowGenerator_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")):
>   (((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlSP_2_ERROR_MESSAGE"))!= null)? "CALL the procedure " + ((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlSP_2_ERROR_MESSAGE")) :
>   (((String)globalMap.get("tFileDelete_1_ERROR_MESSAGE"))!= null)? "tFileDelete " + ((String)globalMap.get("tFileDelete_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")) : " "

You can then send this error description to the email component or display on the console.